# LINQ query throwing 'Conversion from string to type 'Long' is not valid' error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having an issue with the following LINQ query which is throwing the exception in the post title:

```
Dim test = From Match In _
           (From Load In dtContacts _
           Group Join Siebel In dtSiebel _
           On Load("Email") Equals Siebel("EMAIL_ADDRESS") _
           Into g = Group _
           From LoadResults In g.DefaultIfEmpty _
           Where Not LoadResults Is Nothing _
           Select Email_Address = Load.Field(Of String)("Email"), _
                  Load_Account_Number = Load.Field(Of String)("AccountNum")) _
           Group Join Acct In dtSiebel _
           On Match.Email_Address Equals Acct("EMAIL_ADDRESS") _
                And Not Match.Load_Account_Number Equals Acct("ACCOUNT_NUMBER") _
           Into h = Group _
           From MatchResults In h.DefaultIfEmpty _
           Where Not MatchResults Is Nothing _
           Select Contact_Row_ID = MatchResults.Field(Of String)("CONTACT_ROW_ID"), _
                  Match.Email_Address, _
                  Match.Load_Account_Number, _
                  Account_Num_Chk = MatchResults.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
```

The culprit is this line:

```
And Not Match.Load_Account_Number Equals Acct("ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
```

What isn't making sense to me is if I remove the 'Not' clause (which I use for another use case) leaving the rest of the query intact, I get the expected result w/o any exceptions. What is the problem here?

Comment: Try And Not Match.Load_Account_Number Equals  Convert.ToInt64( Acct("ACCOUNT_NUMBER")) _

Comment: Thanks Amit...that threw an 'Input string was not in a correct format' exception

Comment: Ok then you must ensure while using convert that the Acct("ACCOUNT_NUMBER") must contain numeric value in string format. Since you are comparing string to long, so you need either of them to get converted to work.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that the Acct("ACCOUNT_NUMBER") field does not contain numeric values; the format is 'A-12345678'

Comment: and what about Match.Load_Account_Number

Comment: Try this "And Not Match.Load_Account_Number.ToString().Equals( Acct("ACCOUNT_NUMBER"))"

Comment: Both Match.Load_Account_Number and Acct("ACCOUNT_NUMBER") have the exact same formats. The syntax for your suggestion isn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
And Also Not Match.Load_Account_Number Equals Acct("ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
```